# Update current record field after update has been made on it

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called `payment`. With fields `id, end_date, status`. Whenever the payment status is updated to `true` I want to automatically add an `end_date` of CURRENT_DATE. I am trying to write a trigger for this but can't get it to work.

```sql
create function update_date() returns trigger
as $$
    BEGIN
        update payment
        SET end_date = CURRENT_DATE
        END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
CREATE TRIGGER update_date AFTER UDATE ON payment
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION update_date()
```

Comment: Your table has _columns_, not fields.

Answer (score 0):

use a BEFORE trigger and simply assign  the new value:

```
create function update_date() returns trigger
as $$
BEGIN
  new.end_date := current_date;
  return new;
end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER update_date 
  BEFORE UPDATE ON payment
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION update_date()
```

Comment: will this affect all other records? I want to execute this function only for the row it's getting updated, not each row

Comment: is there something like FOR CURRENT ROW instead of FOR EACH ROW?

Comment: This will only update the modified rows. A row level trigger is fired once for each row that was updated, and the `new` record contains exactly that one row.